# Cardinality of a sum(product) of two ordinals equals to sum(product) of their cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

An exercise from Halmos "Naive Set Theory", p. 101:

> Prove that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinal numbers, then 
>   $\text{card}~(\alpha + \beta) = \text{card}~\alpha + \text{card}~\beta$ 
>   and 
>   $\text{card}~(\alpha \cdot \beta) = \text{card}~\alpha 
> \cdot \text{card}~\beta$. Use the ordinal interpretation of the operations on the left side and the cardinal interpretation on the right.

Comment: (pointing out at an obvious problem in my own post)
As a justification on asking a question on what is supposed to be an exercise, I've been working on my own on this book for several years, and this is its last exercise. I believe Halmos got more and more superficial on the latest chapters of his book so without previous exposure to set theory it got more and more difficult to do exercises on my own as I proceeded to the end of the book.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of his definition of ordinal addition and multiplication.

Halmos defines $\alpha+\beta$ to be the order type of $A \oplus B$ (ordinal sum) , where $A,B$ are any two disjoints well-ordered sets with order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Therefore

$$\text{card}~\alpha + \text{card}~\beta=\text{card}~(\alpha\times\{0\} \cup \beta\times\{1\} )=\text{card}~(\alpha+\beta)$$

Similarly Halmos defines $\alpha\cdot\beta$ to be the order type of $A \times B$ (ordinal product) , where $A,B$ are any two well-ordered sets with order types $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Therefore

$$\text{card}~\alpha \cdot \text{card}~\beta=\text{card}~(\alpha\times\beta)=\text{card}~(\alpha \cdot\beta)$$